# How to change the nested array object by checking key `status` in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have a object `obj` , has nested array of object `children`, loop through each object and

check status and remove the object if status is `deleted`.

I have a code below, but partial works and each nested array may/maynot have any number `children`.

How to remove based on condition in javascript

```
removeList =(obj)=>{
  if (obj.length > 0) {
    var result = obj.map(e => {
      if('children' in e)
        e.children = e.children.map(child => {
          if ('children' in child) 
            child.children = child.children.filter(c =>
              c['status'] !== "Deleted"
            );
            return child;
        });      
      return e
    });
    return result;
  }


}
console.log(this.removeList);
var obj = [
  {
   id:1,
   children: [
     {id:1, name: "grocery", status:"active",children:[{id:4, name:"lentils", status:"active"}]},
     {id:2, name: "fruits", status:"deleted"},
     {id:3, name: "coffee", status:"inactive",
       children: [
        {id:6, name:"vegetables", status:"inactive"},
        {id:7, name:"greens", status:"deleted"}
       ]
     }
   ]
  }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[
  {
   id:1,
   children: [
     {id:1, name: "grocery", status:"active",children:[{id:4, name:"lentils", status:"active"}]},
     {id:3, name: "coffee", status:"inactive",
       children: [
        {id:6, name:"vegetables", status:"inactive"}
       ]
     }
   ]

  }
]
```

Comment: So an object has any number of children and each child has itself any number of children? Are the children of the children the same, why do it that way? I suppose those objects reflect your schema, your DB architecture yes? In that case it might be easier to modify your schema to make it simpler and avoid having that many layers of nested objects. Could you share your schema to better understand your situation?

Comment: @Seb thanks for reply, yes, an object has any number of children and each child has itself any number of children

Comment: but are the children the same objects or child 1 is different from child 2 it contains?

Comment: @Seb, its different objects

Comment: What is your current result?

Answer (score 3):

You can use recursion for your solution. Here it is:

```
var obj = [
  {
   id:1,
   children: [
     {id:1, name: "grocery", status:"active",children:[{id:4, name:"lentils", status:"active"}]},
     {id:2, name: "fruits", status:"deleted"},
     {id:3, name: "coffee", status:"inactive",
       children: [
        {id:6, name:"vegetables", status:"inactive"},
        {id:7, name:"greens", status:"deleted"}
       ]
     }
   ]
  }
]

removeList =(obj)=>{
  if (obj.length > 0) {
    var result = []
    obj.forEach(e => {
      if(e.status !== "deleted") { 
        if(e.children && e.children.length > 0) { e.children = removeList(e.children); }
      
        result.push(e) 
      }
    });
    return result;
  }


}
console.log(removeList(obj));
```